# Python syntax (running bempp)

Tags: python

I tried to test a found code in the site of the bempp library (http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bempp/tutorials/blob/master/notebooks/osrc_burton_miller.ipynb). It is a library implemented in python. I have problems when executing the following istructions :

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres

it_count = 0
def iteration_counter(x):
global it_count
it_count += 1

x, info = gmres(discrete_op, rhs_coefficients, callback=iteration_counter)
```

I got the following error message :

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres
>>> 
>>> it_count = 0
>>> def iteration_counter(x):
...     global it_count
...     it_count += 1
...     
... x, info = gmres(discrete_op, rhs_coefficients, callback=iteration_counter)
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    x, info = gmres(discrete_op, rhs_coefficients, callback=iteration_counter)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you help me solving this syntaxe problem please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interactive mode, you need to enter an empty line to terminate multi-line statements. You entered a line with four spaces, which Python interprets as you wanting to continue your function `def`inition.

Comment: @user5396848: That output (garbled as it is) looks like instead of entering an empty line, you just went straight from `it_count += 1` to the `x, info = ...` line. You need to enter an empty line.

Comment: Thanks, I added a new empty line and the problem is fixed